# Why does Image overlap the view above it in a SwiftUI VStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to guarantee that regardless of the image's dimensions, it won't overlap its neighbor sitting above it vertically.

[image]

Here is the code I used.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CardDetailView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Image(.darkColorShade)
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Two of Cups".capitalized)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                   // Spacer(minLength: 100)
                    Image(uiImage: .cardDemo)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 170, height: 150)
                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CardDetailView()
    }
}
```

When I uncomment the Spacer, it adjusts to the location I want.  The Image should appear vertically below the text because it comes after the text in a `VStack`.

[image]

When the spacer is commented, the image overlaps its neighbor if its frame width exceeds its height.  Why is that?

I am just trying to produce a predictable and reliable space between two different views.  I shouldn't just tweak it to appear correct without understanding what is happening.  I also tried setting the background of Image View to red, but that didn't give me any clues to what was happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why does Image overlap the view above it in a SwiftUI VStack?

The image is overflowing its frame. Notice that your frame is wider than it is tall:

```
Image(uiImage: .cardDemo)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(width: 170, height: 150)
```

But it doesn’t look that way onscreen.  The image is oozing over the top and bottom of the frame.  This is what `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` does. It scales the original image proportionally until it fills the frame in each direction overflowing the frame in one direction if necessary.

If you add:

```
    .clipped()
```

It will clip the parts that fall outside of the frame.  Then it will not overlap the objects above it and below it.

---

### How can I ensure the image maintains a certain width and height proportion?

Use `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` or `.scaledToFit()` along with a `frame` that specifies only the `width` or the `height`.  SwiftUI will calculate the other dimension of the `frame` to maintain the image proportions (aspect ratio).

```
Image(uiImage: .cardDemo)
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(width: 170)
```

Comment: How can I ensure the image maintains a certain width and height proportion?

Comment: I updated the answer.  Did that solve your issue?

Comment: I was wanting more like a 2:3 ratio and let the image fit while maintaining its proportions without stretching, and then it would clip the remainder.

Comment: I think your solution is letting the size of the image vary based on its proportions, which is more respectful to the image but less respectful to homogeny if there are slight differences in image size .

Comment: Are the images always portrait? If so, do you want a fixed size or a multiple of screen width or ???

Comment: Ideally I'd like a width relative to the screen width but with a max width so that the Image doesn't become enormous on iPad and landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Using a spacer will try to use all of the space given to that view. My best fix for this would be to manually put a specific amount of padding. For example, under the `Image(uiImage: .cardDemo)` you could put `.padding(.top, 75)`, and that would add some space between `Two of Cups`.

Hope I helped :)